# Find if the element contains "body" add class

Tags: jquery

```
<div class="results">
<div class"right">
<span class="cdh list"><span>
<div>
 <div class="left">
  <ul>
  <li><p><a href="#">link</a> some text</p></li>
  <li><p><a href="#">link</a> some text</p></li>
  <li><p><a href="#">link</a> some text</p></li>
  <li><p><a href="#">link</a> body</p></li>
  </ul>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="results">
 <div class"right">
  <span class="cdh list"><span>
 <div>
 <div class="left">
  <ul>
  <li><p><a href="#">link</a> some text</p></li>
  <li><p><a href="#">link</a> some text</p></li>
  <li><p><a href="#">link</a> some text</p></li>
  <li><p><a href="#">link</a> some text</p></li>
  </ul>
 </div>
</div>
```

I want to find < p > tags that contain "body" (and addClass to) the span tag.
I want add class just to Upper span.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: go to jQuery API and type in top search box `contain` http://api.jquery.com/  4th item is `:contains` selector.... look at examples. WOuld have saved a new question here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a [**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/odujej/1/edit)

Basically go through [each](http://api.jquery.com/each/) of the `p` tags, get the [text content](http://api.jquery.com/text/), if it contains 'body', then [addClass](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) to `span`.

```
$('ul li p').each(function() {
  if ($(this).text().indexOf('body') > -1) {
    $('span').addClass('Test');
  }
});
```

Or a neater way,

```
if ('p:contains("body")') {
      $('span').addClass('Test');
}
```